# Convert hex chars string to int

Tags: disassembly, assembly

For example we have chars buffer with hex value:

char * buff = {"e000"}; //this is our hex value in eax - input for Get_Val().

Then there is function Get_Val() - converts hex (string) to decimal (numbers):

```
cseg01:0004DC00 Get_Val         proc near               ; CODE XREF: Get_DeviceID_Value+97p
cseg01:0004DC00                 push    ebx
cseg01:0004DC01                 push    ecx
cseg01:0004DC02                 push    edx
cseg01:0004DC03                 push    esi
cseg01:0004DC04                 push    edi
cseg01:0004DC05                 push    ebp
cseg01:0004DC06                 mov     ebp, eax        ; ebp = eax = pointer to chars buff
cseg01:0004DC08                 mov     edi, eax        ; edi = eax = pointer to chars buff
cseg01:0004DC0A                 sub     ecx, ecx
cseg01:0004DC0C                 dec     ecx
cseg01:0004DC0D                 xor     eax, eax
cseg01:0004DC0F                 repne scasb
cseg01:0004DC11                 not     ecx
cseg01:0004DC13                 dec     ecx
cseg01:0004DC14                 xor     ebx, ebx
cseg01:0004DC16                 xor     esi, esi
cseg01:0004DC18                 lea     edx, ds:0[ecx*4]
cseg01:0004DC1F
cseg01:0004DC1F next_loop:                              ; CODE XREF: Get_Val+3Ej
cseg01:0004DC1F                 mov     eax, ebx
cseg01:0004DC21                 inc     ebx
cseg01:0004DC22                 mov     al, [eax+ebp]
cseg01:0004DC25                 and     eax, 0FFh
cseg01:0004DC2A                 call    Get_Digit
cseg01:0004DC2F                 imul    eax, off_C6D28[edx]
cseg01:0004DC36                 sub     edx, 4
cseg01:0004DC39                 dec     ecx
cseg01:0004DC3A                 add     esi, eax
cseg01:0004DC3C                 test    ecx, ecx
cseg01:0004DC3E                 ja      short next_loop
cseg01:0004DC40                 mov     eax, esi
cseg01:0004DC42                 pop     ebp
cseg01:0004DC43                 pop     edi
cseg01:0004DC44                 pop     esi
cseg01:0004DC45                 pop     edx
cseg01:0004DC46                 pop     ecx
cseg01:0004DC47                 pop     ebx
cseg01:0004DC48                 retn
cseg01:0004DC48 Get_Val         endp
```

Function Get_Digit returns one digit - corresponds to chars buffer, one digit from 0 to 15, for example our hex 'e' has numeric value 14 decimal, and Get_Digit returns for our example 14 decimal.

```
cseg01:0004DC4C Get_Digit       proc near               ; CODE XREF: Get_Val+2Ap
cseg01:0004DC4C                 push    ebx
cseg01:0004DC4D                 push    ecx
cseg01:0004DC4E                 push    edx
cseg01:0004DC4F                 mov     ecx, off_C6D28
cseg01:0004DC55                 mov     bl, al
cseg01:0004DC57                 xor     eax, eax
cseg01:0004DC59
cseg01:0004DC59 next_loop:                              ; CODE XREF: Get_Digit+1Dj
cseg01:0004DC59                 lea     edx, [ecx+eax]
cseg01:0004DC5C                 cmp     bl, [edx]
cseg01:0004DC5E                 jz      short on_exit
cseg01:0004DC60                 cmp     bl, [edx+10h]
cseg01:0004DC63                 jz      short on_exit
cseg01:0004DC65                 inc     eax
cseg01:0004DC66                 cmp     eax, 10h
cseg01:0004DC69                 jb      short next_loop
cseg01:0004DC6B                 mov     eax, 0FFFFFFFFh
cseg01:0004DC70
cseg01:0004DC70 on_exit:                                ; CODE XREF: Get_Digit+12j
cseg01:0004DC70                                         ; Get_Digit+17j
cseg01:0004DC70                 mov     off_C6D28, ecx
cseg01:0004DC76                 pop     edx
cseg01:0004DC77                 pop     ecx
cseg01:0004DC78                 pop     ebx
cseg01:0004DC79                 retn
cseg01:0004DC79 Get_Digit       endp
```

Where off_C6D28 is:

```
dseg05:000C6D28 off_C6D28       dd offset a0123456789abcd
```

```
dseg05:000C11BC a0123456789abcd db '0123456789ABCDEF0123456789abcdef',0
```

My question is - what is this means in func Get_Val():

```
imul    eax, off_C6D28[edx]
```

What is value of edx:

```
lea     edx, ds:0[ecx*4]
```

And how arranged exit from loop (I dont understand what happens with ecx inside loop):

```
cseg01:0004DC1F next_loop:                              ; CODE XREF: Get_Val+3Ej
cseg01:0004DC1F                 mov     eax, ebx
cseg01:0004DC21                 inc     ebx
cseg01:0004DC22                 mov     al, [eax+ebp]
cseg01:0004DC25                 and     eax, 0FFh
cseg01:0004DC2A                 call    Get_Digit
cseg01:0004DC2F                 imul    eax, off_C6D28[edx]
cseg01:0004DC36                 sub     edx, 4
cseg01:0004DC39                 dec     ecx
cseg01:0004DC3A                 add     esi, eax
cseg01:0004DC3C                 test    ecx, ecx
cseg01:0004DC3E                 ja      short next_loop
```

Thanks in advance.